# Responsive Website not working with Media Queries in Css

Tags: css, responsive

I am running a small website on Joomla and cannot get the responsiveness to work. I am running media queries for the screen sizes and making adjustments as needed, but cannot get them to adjust for anything under 760px wide.

I've checked all four of my media queries and cannot find a solution. I'm sure it's something simple, but I cannot find it. I do

```
/* Note: Design for a width of 768px */

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
.main, #jf-footer .main-inner1 {
width: 768px;
}}
```

---

```
/* Note: Design for a width of 480px */

@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
.main, #jf-footer .main-inner1 {
width: 444px;
}}
```

---

```
/* Note: Design for a width of 320px */

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px){
.main, #jf-footer .main-inner1 {
width: 316px;
}}
```

I expect the main DIV to scale for 768px, 480px and 320px, but cannot get it to scale properly.

The website is located at:
https://crafted-development.com

My Css is located at:
https://www.crafted-development.com/templates/jf_calla-exteriors/css/template.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close the media tag also at the end with "}"
Also, instead of media, try adding "@media only screen and"
Example::

```
/* Note: Design for a width of 320px */

    @media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px){
      .main, #jf-footer .main-inner1 {
        width: 316px;
      }
    }
```

Also, the meta tag is necessary

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: I noticed that in the question I didn't include them. My CSS file is longer for each media query, I just shortened them for the question. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Also, you need to add "@media only screen and", updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Use this css

```
     @media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 959px) {
    .main, #jf-footer .main-inner1 {
    width: 768px !important;
    }
    }

    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 480px) and (max-device-width: 767px) {
    .main, #jf-footer .main-inner1 {
    width: 444px !important;
    }
}

    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 479px)
    {
    .main, #jf-footer .main-inner1 {
    width: 316px !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be the solution: Thank you guys!

```
/* Note: Design for a width of 320px */

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px){
  .main, #jf-footer .main-inner1 {
    width: 316px;
  }
}
```